# Show that $f(x) :=\cos(\cos(x))$ is a contraction mapping. Find the fixed point.

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces, banach-fixed-point

> Show that $f(x) := \cos(\cos(x))$ is a contraction mapping. Find the fixed point.

I know that $|\cos(x)|\leq 1$ which means that $|\cos(\cos(x))| \in [\cos 0,\cos 1]$

I need to find $\alpha <1$ s.t.

$$|\cos(\cos(x)) - \cos(\cos(y))| \leq \alpha d|x-y| .$$

Comment: Note that $\cos 1 < \cos 0$, so (since $\cos x$ is even and decreasing on $[0, 1]$) we have $|\cos \cos x| \in [\cos 1, \cos 0] = [\cos 1, 1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interval $X:=\bigl[0,{\pi\over2}\bigr]$ the function $\cos$ decreases monotonically from $1$ to $0$. Therefore $f:=\cos\circ\cos$ increases from $\cos 1>\cos{\pi\over3}={1\over2}$ to $\cos0=1$. It follows that we can consider  the restriction  $f\restriction X$ as a selfmap of the complete metric space $X$.

Furthermore we have
$$0\leq f'(x)=\sin(\cos x)\cdot\sin x\leq\sin 1\cdot1<\sin{\pi\over3}={\sqrt{3}\over2}\qquad(x\in X)\ ,$$
and this shows that $f$ is a contraction of $X$. According to the fixed point theorem we therefore have a unique fixed point $\xi$ of the restriction $f\restriction X$.

It remains to show that there are no fixed points of $f$ outside of $X$: From $$f({\mathbb R})=\cos\bigl([{-1},1]\bigr)\subset\left[{1\over2},1\right]$$ it immediately follows that there can be no fixed points $\xi<0$ or $\xi>{\pi\over2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :).I like this answer better, but I didnt want to unmark the other answer. I hope that's okay with you.

Comment: I got you used here statement:If $f:[a,b]\to [a,b]$ be differentiable,then $f$ is a contraction if and only if $f'(x)\leq r<1,\forall x\in [a,b]$My Question is can I use this statement to show  $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is  not contraction or the statement is valid only for close intervals?

Comment: @mathstudent: $X$ has to be a complete metric space, and $f$ has to satisfy $d\bigl(f(x),f(y)\bigr)\leq r d(x,y)$ for some $r<1$. Then we have exactly one fixed point. $X={\mathbb R}$ is o.k.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Computing gives $$f'(x) = \sin \cos x \sin x ,$$ and so $$|f'(x)| = |\sin \cos x| \, |\sin x|.$$
Thus, $|f'(x)| \leq 1$, and if equality holds for some $a$ we would have $|\sin \cos a| = 1$ and $|\sin a| = 1$. (It may also be useful to observe that $f$, and hence $f'$, is periodic.)

Comment: This does not exclude a priori the possibility that the supremum is 1.

Comment: @Travis so I should shift $\cos(x)=sin(x+ \pi / 2)$ and show that there isn't $x$ that works? Clearly $|\sin^2(x) \times \sin (x+\pi/2) |<1$ but I don't clear is enough

Comment: @Did That is the purpose of the additional hint that $f'$ is periodic: It guarantees (using the continuity of $f'$) that the image of $f'$ is compact.

Comment: @GRS I'm not quite sure what you mean. Suppose that $|\sin a| = 1$; what does this tell you about the value of $\cos a$? And what does that tell you about the value of $|\sin \cos a|$? Is it possible to have both $|\sin \cos a| = 1$ and $|\sin a| = 1$ for some value of $a$?

Comment: @Travis not possible, how would I proceed to find the fixed point? I suppose that $x_n=f(x_{n+1})$ I build a Cauchy sequence, but where does it converge? I know that it converges to somewhere in the domain.

Comment: @GRS Note that if $x$ is a fixed point of $f$, it is also a fixed point of $f \circ f$. In this case, I believe the fixed point does not have a closed-form expression; are you supposed to give, e.g., a numerical value for it? See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html

Comment: I found that $\cos x = x$ is the fixed point. I don't know how this is achieved, but it's also a fixed point of $\cos (cos x)$

Comment: @Travis Thanks, I'll do some more reading on it

Comment: @GRS You're welcome, I hope you found it useful. If you are looking for a numerical approximation, this is a standard application of Newton's Method.